# Azure Runbook - Logging

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

What is the log retention policy for Azure Runbook jobs? For how long the logs of my runbook jobs will be retained in Azure? 6months or 5 years or till lifetime/deletion of the runbook resource?

Any possibility of exporting these logs to our own storage?

[image: Screenshot Attached]

Answer (score 0):

As per this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-managing-data article the Azure Automation automatically deletes and permanently removes 
jobs older than 90 days. So IMHO it should hold good for its logs as well.

And yes, AFAIK there is possibility of exporting runbook job logs to storage account by following below two articles. Out of which the first one explains about sending the data to Azure Monitor logs and the second one explains about sending that data to storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-to-storage

You may give a try with this approach and see if it accomplishes your requirement.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Links are 404 now, any chance you saved their content?